# Invalid branch / Duplicate Branch

Tags: xcode, git

I am working on a project with the master branch. Then I created a branch out of master called "dev". Now I push my code to dev.

Unfortunately now I see a duplicate branch of dev called "dev 2" under section remote -> origin (as in the given picture)

[image]

Could somebody please tell how it was created and now how to get rid of it.

Now when I pull from Xcode I get the following error:

the given reference name 'refs/remotes/origin/dev 2' is not valid (-12)

Comment: Are you storing your repository in a cloud-managed space, e.g., Dropbox or iCloud or some such?

Comment: @torek no! I tried to delete it from Xcode but it is still showing up in Xcode but not in Gitlab.

Comment: *Something* created this, and that's a symptom of using iCloud or similar on a Git repository. But you can get Git to delete it, with `git fetch --prune` on the command line.